# Command to compile imported classes

Tags: java

Suppose that I need to run my Java program. This program imports some Java class. So I need to compile dependency class and my program. After this I can run my program.

I do something like this:

`$ javac program.java path/to/dependency/class.java && java program`

Is there any attribute to automatically compile this dependency class? Or I need to use something like Maven for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the normal compile command, all imported classes that are found as source files (rather than already compiled classes) will be compiled as well.